# I left my job 2 years ago in 2013 and I am joining a new company now in 2015 . Can I still have my old EPF account transferred to the present one?

Tags: india, retirement-plan, job-change

I was working in tech space for period of 10 months before quitting my job to go for higher studies in 2013. Somehow I never withdrew any money nor contributed anything to my EPF account after quitting my job. The account still exists in the database of epfindia.gov.in .

Now in 2015 i will be joining another company next month.

My query is that can i still transfer my old EPF account to my present one with my current employer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can transfer the balance in the old EPF to your new account. When joining the new company ask them to give you a form that will help you transfer your old EPF to new one.

Note its not the company's responsibility to get it transferred, generally they try and help out the employees.